# c++ returns last element in array

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

I have text file that looks like this:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4
word5 word6 word7 word8
word9 word10..
```

Then I open file and read all lines into array after that I run cycle to split all text words into separate elements (so array looks like this "myarray  = {"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5...}")

```
String^ fileName = "text.txt";
cli::array<String^> ^ myarray= File::ReadAllLines(fileName);
for (int a = 0; a < myarray->Length; ++a)
{
cli::array<String^> ^ words = myarray[a]->Split(' ');
}
```

My problem is that after running the code and telling program show me words [0] instead of getting output of "word1" I getting the last word in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a little more detail is in order. For example, you say "show me `element[0]`...", but there's nothing in the code named `element`.

That being said, your inner loop creates a new array every time, so it's only ever going to hold the last line from the file, split into tokens, of course.

Maybe try this:

```
String^ fileName = "text.txt";
cli::array<String^> ^ myarray= File::ReadAllLines(fileName);
List<String ^> ^ words = new List<String ^>();
for (int a = 0; a < myarray->Length; ++a)
{
    words->AddRange(myarray[a]->Split(' ');
}
```

This way, you're accumulating all of the 'words' into one large list that's available outside the loop.  You can access `List` elements with the `[]` operator, just like an array.